# how to call methods/components in webpack bundle output?

Tags: webpack, reactjs

Looking for a way to do following, is it possible?

```
// main.jsx
export default class Main extends React.Component {}

// include webpack bundle output and call it from html template
<div>
<script src="/webpack/app-bundle.js"></script>
<script>Main() /** call method in bundle **/ </script>
</div>
```

For instance, webpack able to "expose" jquery with this config:

```
{ test: require.resolve('jquery'), loader: 'expose?$' }
```

Similarly is there a way to "expose" app defined react component? Thanks.

Comment: What is your use case exactly ?

Comment: For example to render "Main" with props base on server runtime data (without doing additional ajax call).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider this the other way, i.e : communicating between your main file to your bundle. Do to this, you can attach some data to the `window` object, this will define globally available variables you can access in your bundle.

For example :

```
// main.jsx
export default class Main extends React.Component { render() => <div>{this.props.foo}</div> }

ReactDOM.render(<Main foo={window.MYAPP.foo}/>, document.getElementById('app'))

// include webpack bundle output and call it from html template
<div id="app></div>
<script>window.MYAPP.foo = 'bar'</script>
<script src="/webpack/app-bundle.js"></script>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Similar to what you suggested, I end up used <script type="application/json" /> in html template to avoid the use of "window". Anyway, it would be nice if webpack can support the use case of exporting App defined react component in future.

Comment: You're welcome. But for me, exporting from webpack is a non sense. The whole point of webpack is to bundle up all your js files into one (on many) bundles, to encapsulate all the code in chunks. The communication should only be one way only : external => webpack bundles, not webpack bundle => external.

Comment: I understand your point. However webpack do allow us to expose npm components right.